# How do I reset my ripping folder in Windows Media Player 12?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-player

When I go to the ripping options in Windows Media Player 12 to change the location where CD's should be ripped to, the location is blank. If I click on the `Change` location button nothing happens, I don't get a window open to let me browse to a new location.

There was previously a friends portable disk attached to the machine so he could rip his CD's but that's been removed and that ripping location no longer exists. I also no longer have access to his portable drive any more.

Thinking that this might be stored in the registry, I had a look through the media player registry key at:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences`

but nothing jumps out as being the possible location where this setting is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried plugging a removable drive back in and changing the library location then? Any drive would do as it should reuse the same drive letter.

The only other thing I can think of is to type in the location rather than trying to browse.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because there is a problem with the default **Music library folder**.  Follow these instructions to fix the library.

See this link for instructions and screen shots: [Library-ms is no longer working](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26856-library-ms-no-longer-working-fix-windows-7-8-a.html)

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. Delete any library that you are getting this error with. 
   NOTE: Deleting a library does not delete the contents of the library.
3. If prompted by Recycle Bin, click Yes to confirm deletion of library.
4. When finished deleting affected libraries, right click on **Libraries** in the navigation pane, and click **Restore Default Libraries**.
5. Start Windows Media Player. Open **Tools > Options**. Select the **Rip Music** tab. Click **Change...** and set the rip music location.

Answer (score 1):

- Start Media Player
- Right click "Music"
- Choose "Manage Music Library"
- Edit the list so that there are no "Unavailable" items (your friends
  portable disk)